# How to write a Regex that matches all except a String that contains a line break in it?

Tags: regex

I've been trying to compare PDF files by extracting text from them using `PDFUtil` library for selenium with `excludeText()` method,
How do I match anything except a string that contains a line break inside of it which appears like this?

```
Settlement
Approval Rule
```

I've been using this Regex:

```
^(Settlement\nApproval Rule)
```

Doesn't work though

Comment: PDFUtil for selenium

Comment: excludeText() method

Comment: Please mention this in queston.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, done

Comment: Can you elaborate more? "match anything except a string that contains a line break inside" is difficult to confine.

Comment: If the given string is "Settlement\nApproval Rule" then the Regex returns false else if
the given string is not "Settlement\nApproval Rule" then the Regex returns true
Like "fdk,l,fkdl,fkl" returns true but "Settlement\nApproval Rule" returns false